# Directive: Get attr scope-value in the templateUrl function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is the directive that I wanna build:

```
module.directive('templater', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
        return attrs.templater;
    }
};
});
```

but, as you may know, in this HTML:

```
<div 
    ng-repeat="item in items" 
    templater="item.template">
</div>
```

accessing `attrs.templater` simply gives `item.template` instead of the actual template url string.

How do you access the data inside `attrs.templater` without going inside the linking function?
I want to leverage the simplicity of the `templateUrl` function, also, avoid the reflow overhead in the linking function.

Answer (score 0):

***EDITED:** My original assumption was wrong.*

Since `item.template` is meaningful only in the context of a scope and since the template-fetching/compiling happens at a point in time when there is no info regarding scopes there doesn't seem to be a way to fetch the template prior to the linking phase.

Comment: and then access it like attrs.templater? I still get it as a string, like this: "{{item.template}}"

Comment: I just checked, that kind of evaluation takes place inside the linking function. Meaning if I access 'attrs.templater' inside the linking function, I get the evaluated data, but not in the templateUrl function.

Comment: @Birowsky: I am afraid yu are right. There doesn't seem to be a way to access that data prior to linking.

Comment: so, based on this, do you agree that I should do what I want inside the link function?

Comment: @Birowsky: I don't see any other possible way.

Comment: At least we're on the same page :}