# angular js, controller variable not able to read in directive

Tags: angularjs-scope

Below is rough code not Fully syntax

/  JS FILE
(function() {

```
var app     = angular.module('ngABC', []);
var nodes     = [];



 Here is the controller to get all node fron server using http
  app.controller('nodesController', function($scope,$http){
           $http({
                url:        $url,
                method:     "POST",
                data:       postData,
                headers :   {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

            }).success(function(response) {  
              $Scope.nodes = response;
           });
  });
```

//Response  is like 
[{"basic":{"node_id":"8","title":"NEWS TOPIC","alias":"news-topic","created_by":12345 "}}]
........

```
This is the directive to get node owner's user name.
app.directive('username', function() { 
   restrict       = 'E';
    templateUrl    = function(ent,attr){ 
          return url+attr.userid; 
                 }
```

});

//======== This is .php FILE , Display's All the NODE,

```
<div ng-repeat="x in nodes">
          {{ x.basic.node_id}}                                 // printing as "8"
          {{ x.basic.title}}                                   // printing "NEWS TOPIC"
         <username userid="{{x.basic.created_by}}"></username>        

         //Here need's owner Name. SO i am using Directive ANd 
         by templateUrl and going to server with userid to get his NAME  
         Directive should take user_id as "12345" but taking as "{{x.basic.created_by}}"



</div>
```

I want templateUrl like   "url/get_name/12345",
But it is taking like     "url/get_name/{{x.basic.created_by}}"

Comment: Your code is a jumbled, nonsensical mess. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing both the code and the data which it uses.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Is it clear now?

Comment: yes, much clearer except for the exact question. What variable are you not able to read?

Comment: not able to read {{x.basic.created_by}}  in directive

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911540/directive-get-attr-scope-value-in-the-templateurl-function

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces in your
`<username userid="{{x.basic.created_by}}"></username>`

Write it like `<username userid="x.basic.created_by"></username>`